# request is going in lowerase but i need it to go in uppercase

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl

I am using php curl for sending an xml request. In my request some of the field name should start with upper case letter (I am mentioning those field names exactly how it should be). but it is still going as lowercase. what should i do for this?

Comment: Show us some code and be specific about *it* and *going*.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the server end that is lowercasing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$soap_request  ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> "
."<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>"
//. "<soapenv:Header /> "
.  "<soapenv:Body>"
."<air:AirFareRulesreq targetbranch=\"P107616\" Fareruletype=\"Long\" xmlns:air=\"http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v16_0\" xmlns:com=\"http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v13_0\" >" 
."<com:BillingPointOfSaleInfo OriginApplication=\"UAPI\">" ."</com:BillingPointOfSaleInfo>"
."<air:FareRuleKey FareInfoRef=$farere ProviderCode=\"1G\">$farerulekk"
."</air:FareRuleKey> " 
."</air:AirFareRuleReq>"
. "</soapenv:Body>"
."</soapenv:Envelope>"
."?>";
```

Comment: This is how I am formatting the xml request. normal concatination

Comment: @MrCode: I am sure it is not the server end making it as lowercase